# How forecasting with LSTM model with Keras with event-based sample data? Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I would like to do anomaly detection on a sensor, my data is recorded according to a change in value of +/- X%.

From one value to another I can have a very short or very long time difference. The problem is that when I want to train my model or make predictions, the LSTM will create a window of X timestep and move it by one time step for example.

But if between each value of my data the time is variable how could I say for example that I want the prediction in 50 days? While the time associated to the time steps is variable...

Is there any work to be done on data formatting or configuration on the LSTM time window and how please?

```
Timestamp               Value
2017-07-03 07:10:52.8   48.83
2017-07-03 07:12:09.3   48.42
2017-07-03 07:12:22.0   48.67
2017-07-03 07:32:52.6   48.05
2017-07-03 07:33:23.0   48.11
```